Does every cyclic quadrilaterals has two consecutive sides such that each of these sides and the two diagonals satisfy the triangle inequality?
Consider a cyclic quadrilateral as shown in the figure below where $a,c$ and $b,d$ are the pair of opposite side and $e,f$ are the diagonals.

My simulations show that

One or both the triplets $(e,f,a)$ and $(e,f,c)$ always satisfy the triangle inequality
One or both the triplets $(e,f,b)$ and $(e,f,d)$ always satisfy the triangle inequality


Conjecture: Given any two of opposite sides of a cyclic quadrilateral, there exists a triangle with at least one of these two sides and the two diagonals as the sides of a triangle. Or equivalently any cyclic quadrilaterals as at least two consecutive sides such that each of these two sides and the two diagonals satisfy the triangle inequality.

Can this conjecture be proved?

Changing-up some notation, consider cyclic $\square ABCD$ whose diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ meet at $O$. Define $a:=|OA|$, $b:=|OB|$, $c:=|OC|$, $d:=|OD|$, and $\theta :=\angle AOB$. Note that we can write $ac=bd=p^2$, where $p^2$ is power of $O$ with respect to the circle. Also, by the Law of Cosines, $$|AB|^2=a^2+b^2-2a b \cos\theta \qquad |CD|^2=c^2+d^2-2cd\cos\theta$$

The ostensible triangle formed from diagonals $|AC|$ and $|BD|$, and side $|AB|$, inherits one aspect of the Triangle Inequality from $\triangle OAB$:
$$|AB|<a+b\leq(a+c)+(b+d)=|AC|+|BD| \tag1$$ The other aspects require
$$|AB|+|BD|-|AC|>0 \qquad |AB|-|BD|+|AC|>0 \tag2$$
As the expressions on the right-hand sides have sum $2|AB|$, they cannot both be negative; thus, their mutual positivity is assured if their product is positive.
$$\begin{align}
0 &< |AB|^2 - (|BD|-|AC|)^2 \\[4pt]
&= a^2+b^2-2a b\cos\theta-((b+d)-(a+c))^2 \\[4pt]
&=2ab(1-\cos\theta)-(c - d) (2 a - 2 b + c - d) \\[4pt]
&=\left( 2ab(1-\cos\theta)+\frac{p^2(a - b)^2}{a b} \right) \;+\; \frac{p^2(a - b)^2}{a^2b^2} (a b - p^2) \\[4pt]
&=(\text{positive}) \;+\; (\text{non-negative})\cdot (ab-p^2) \tag3
\end{align}$$
Likewise, for the ostensible triangle made from the diagonals and opposite side $CD$, we'd need
$$\begin{align}
0 &< (\text{positive}) \;+\; (\text{non-negative})\cdot (cd-p^2) \\
&= (\text{positive}) \;\color{red}{-}\; (\text{non-negative}) \cdot \frac{p^2}{ab}(ab-p^2) \tag4 
\end{align}$$
Now, if $ab-p^2$ is non-negative (respectively, non-positive) then condition $(3)$ (respectively, $(4)$) holds. (The other condition may-or-may-not hold in each case.) Either way, at least one of the ostensible triangles is indeed valid.
Likewise, this holds for ostensible triangles formed with the diagonals and either side $|BC|$ or $|DA|$. The conjecture is verified. $\square$

Preamble: We use OP's notation (not to be mixed up with Blue's notation).
We will show that $(\max(a, c) , e, f)$ form a triangle.
The triangle inequality gives us $ e + f > a + c > \max(a, c) $. So it remains to show that $ |e-f| < \max (a, c)$.
In fact, we will show a stronger statement, namely that $|e-f| < |a - c | < \max(a, c)$.
As an aside, since $e+f > a+c > |a-c|$, this also proves that $(e, f, |a-c|)$ form a triangle. This will be useful for OP's followup question, whose solution just uses this fact.
Solution:

Ptolemy's theorem states that $ef = ac + bd$, $e^2 = (ac+bd) \frac{ad + bc } {ab+ cd } $, and $f^2 = (ac+bd) \frac{ ab+cd} { ad+bc}$.

Verify the algebraic manipulation that
$$ \begin{array} { l l } |e-f|^2 & = e^2 - 2ef + f^2 \\
& = (ac+bd)[ \frac{ad + bc } {ab+ cd } +    -2 + \frac{ ab+cd} { ad+bc}  ] \\
& = (ac+bd) \frac{( a-c)^2(b-d)^2}{(ab+cd)(ad+bc)}. \end{array}     $$

Verify the algebraic manipulation that


$$ \begin{array} { l l} & |e-f|^2  < |a-c|^2  \\
 \Leftrightarrow  &  (ac+bd)(b-d)^2 < (ab+cd)(ad+bc) \\
\Leftrightarrow & bd (d -a-b-c) ( b-a-c-d) > 0 . \end{array} $$

The final inequality is true, due to the quadrilateral inequality that states $ d > a+b+c, b > a+c+d$.

In particular, the triangles $(e, f, |a-c|), (e, f , |b-d|)$ are not degenerate iff the cyclic  quadrilateral $(a, b, c, d)$ is not degenerate. In that sense, this is the strongest statement we can make.


